# Each and using %w in controller Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, schema

I have the following which works well:

```
with_in_schemas :only => %w{schema1 schema2} do
   @user = User.count
end
```

and output such as

```
@user => 14
```

I want schema name get from account,i have this :

```
@accounts = Account.all
@accounts.each do |t|
with_in_schemas :only => t.schema  do
   @user = User.count
end
end
```

but output is zero

```
@user => 0
```

on `schema1` have 14 `user` and `schema2` have 0 user.

UPDATE

I tried add 1 user to `schema2`

and now `schema1` have 14 `user` and `schema2` have 1 user.

and on controller

```
@accounts = Account.all
 @accounts.each do |t|
    with_in_schemas :only => t.schema  do
       @user = User.count
    end
 end
```

and output

```
@user => 1
```

I want to count of user from `schema1` and `schema2`

```
@accounts = Account.all
@count_user = 0
   @accounts.each do |t|
      with_in_schemas :only => t.schema  do
         @user = User.count
      end
      @count_user = @count_user + @user
   end
```

and output

```
@count_user => 2
```

why only last schema get count of user table?

Comment: What is `t.schema`? Do you actually have a schema by that name? And if so, does it's users table have any records?

Comment: So does `t.schema` return an Array or just a single string corresponding to a schema?

Comment: corrected, my question have updated.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: why only last schema get count of user table?

Comment: What out put do you want? Do you want it to be `15`?? If not, what do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@user = 0
schemas = Account.all.map(&:schema)

with_in_schemas :only => schemas  do
  @user += User.count
end
```

Comment: output @user => 2 , i'm really confused.

Comment: @anonymousxxx, are you sure you still have 15 users?

Comment: yes, i try this `with_in_schemas :only => %w{schema1 schema2} do
   @user = User.count
end` output @user => 15 .. ok i change my question, how can `account` schema (`schema1`, `schema2`) into `%w`, so it would be like `w%{schema1 schema2}`

Comment: @anonymousxxx - Are you sure your accounts belong to both schema1 and schema2? Your accounts probably only belong to schema2.

Comment: yes i sure, look schreenshot for account table on `public schema` http://i.cubeupload.com/Rb3Fgs.png, user on `schema1`  http://i.cubeupload.com/ee3Pr7.png, user on `schema2` http://i.cubeupload.com/Pv1Dql.png

Comment: @anonymousxxx, I changed my answer. Could you try my suggestion?

Comment: sorry mischa, everything does not work, it looks like issue of gem `multi_schema`, but thanks, you are really good person..

Comment: no problem, btw, corrected my post when i try this `with_in_schemas :only => %w{schema1 schema2} do @user = User.count` end output @user => 1 not 15, so counted is `schema2` only